# Фильтр в Angularjs не равно

Tags: angularjs

Как сделать фильтр с условием не равно

Тут равно live

```
quests.items|filter:{publish:1,groupe:'live'}
```

Нужно сделать `!= live`
сделал через `ng-hide="item.groupe == 'live'"`, 
но интересно как фильтром убрать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В [справке](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter) указывается:

> The predicate can be negated by prefixing the string with !.

Это значит, чтобы обратить предикат строка должна начинаться со знака "!"

```
quests.items|filter:{publish:1,groupe:'!live'}
```

**Важно:** `filter` в ангуляре проверяет не *равенство*, а *вхождение*, то есть не

```
a == b
```

а

```
a.contains(b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Один из способов использовать кастомные фильтры, описывая из работу в директиве или контроллере, к контексте которого, происходит фильтрация.
Подробнее есть [тут](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

Там же можно найти описание того, как фильтр может обращаться к фкнункции за зачением для фильтрации.